# Grails run-app : ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException: warning can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type com.sun.proxy.$Proxy51

Tags: grails, aspectj, spring-cache

while executing one app in dev mode with grails (run-app), i'm facing one issue related to AOP. 
I'm using spring cache to cache some services method, and when i try to call one of them, i have this exception :

**Note : This app works fine when deployed in external tomcat**

```
 org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException: warning can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type com.sun.proxy.$Proxy51
 [Xlint:cantFindType]
at org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.ReflectionWorld$ExceptionBasedMessageHandler.handleMessage(ReflectionWorld.java:129)
at org.aspectj.weaver.Lint$Kind.signal(Lint.java:340)
at org.aspectj.weaver.MissingResolvedTypeWithKnownSignature.raiseCantFindType(MissingResolvedTypeWithKnownSignature.java:232)
at org.aspectj.weaver.MissingResolvedTypeWithKnownSignature.getDeclaredInterfaces(MissingResolvedTypeWithKnownSignature.java:86)
at org.aspectj.weaver.ResolvedType.getDirectSupertypes(ResolvedType.java:82)
at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.TypePattern.matchesSubtypes(TypePattern.java:178)
at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.TypePattern.matchesStatically(TypePattern.java:130)
at org.aspectj.weaver.internal.tools.TypePatternMatcherImpl.matches(TypePatternMatcherImpl.java:31)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.TypePatternClassFilter.matches(TypePatternClassFilter.java:101)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.DefaultAdvisorChainFactory.getInterceptorsAndDynamicInterceptionAdvice(DefaultAdvisorChainFactory.java:64)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.AdvisedSupport.getInterceptorsAndDynamicInterceptionAdvice(AdvisedSupport.java:489)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:193)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy53.list(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor$1.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:52)
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.invokeOperation(CacheAspectSupport.java:317)
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:350)
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:299)
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:61)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy53.list(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Maybe you're injecting an implementation and you are using JDK proxy (that only exposes the interface). Very hard to know with only the stacktrace. Check the `proxy-target-class` attribute in [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#cache-annotation-enable)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think code and configuration are ok, because once deployed in external tomcat, it works fine. I have this issue only in devel mode